# Mapping on changing list

Tags: associations, map

for those who have seen it, I have deleted my previous question, as suggested by @Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ,

The goal :

***Modifying dynamically the list on which a mapping is done***

I try to give you a concrete example:

When I do this :

```
 S = Association[];
AssociateTo[S, {1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three"}]

While[Length[S] > 0,
 (KeyDropFrom[S, Keys[S][[#]]];
    Print[S];) & /@ Range[Length[Keys[S]]]]
```

The output is :

```
    Out[19]= <|1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three"|>

During evaluation of In[18]:= <|2->two,3->three|>

During evaluation of In[18]:= <|2->two|>

During evaluation of In[18]:= Part::partw: Part 3 of {2} does not exist.

During evaluation of In[18]:= <|2->two|>

During evaluation of In[18]:= <||>
```

As you can see, mathematica does not understand that I want the list on which the mapping is done to be modfied dynamically, S is only evaluated once at the beginning of the mapping : 
the desired output would be just `<||>`, with no errors. 
***I just want to modify dynamically the liston which the mapping is done***, my goal *is not to delete all the keys of an association*...

Can anyone help me ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: `S` is modified dynamically, that is why `Print[S]` changes on every evaluation.The problem is that `Range[Length[Keys[S]]]` is only evaluated once.

Comment: why not `While[Length[S] > 0, (KeyDropFrom[S, #];
    Print[S];) & /@ Keys[S]]`  or `While[(Length[KeyDropFrom[S, #] > 0];
    Print[S];) & /@ Keys[S]]`?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, yes indeed, does not solve my problem, but I will edit my post.

Comment: @kglr, does not solve my problem Keys[s] is still evaluated once. Again my goal is not to empty S...